# Why is mutt choking with atom as the editor?

Tags: atom-editor, mutt

I am trying to get mutt to use atom (or gedit, actually) as the editor and it keeps aborting.

I added `set editor = "atom"` to my `.muttrc` and it launches atom with an empty document named "/tmp/mutt-1000-2629012345" but inside of Mutt I get "Aborted unmodified message".

Is there a trick to coaxing Mutt into using an external editor?

Comment: You get that message if the file was not modified. This happens if you quit the editor without saving. Probably atom opens the file in background and the command returns immediately. Try something like `atom --wait`.

Comment: Closer, but that hangs everything up. I have to "ctrl-c" to get back to the message. I'd like to be able to close/save my text file and get all the way back to the composed message in mutt.